# How to use between condition with numbers for string columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to check the between condition for two numbers in the tables but the column in oracle DB has string values .

I tried the following query , nothing helped me

```
select * from  sys.employee_infor where  to_number(emp_number) between 1200 and 2400;

select * from  sys.employee_infor where (emp_number) >= to_char(1200) and (emp_number)  <= to_char(2400);

select * from  sys.employee_infor where  to_number(emp_number) between '1200' and '2400';
```

Received error as :

> ORA-01722: invalid number

My Emp_number column be like as,

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? why will you use string type store number value in `emp_number` column?

Comment: Consider not using SYS schema for your own data. SYS (and SYSTEM) are special, leave them alone. If you do something *unexpected*, you might destroy the database. Create another user and do whatever you're doing there.

Comment: **NEVER**, **ever** create your own tables in the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schema. Create a regular user and create your tables there. Do **NOT** use `SYS` or `SYSTEM` for your application ar anything else than doing DBA work. Just don't

Comment: My Column will be like this

Answer (score 2):

The [safer solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a6271d5799c4bb075323322f931e618) is to use `CASE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.employee_infor
WHERE CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(emp_number, '\D') THEN TO_NUMBER(emp_number) END BETWEEN 1200 AND 2400
```

Comment: REGEXP_LIKE is taking long time to run the query , I need to include this sub query into the main query and Sys is just a example one the user name is different from sys.Please help me to fix the issue

Comment: The correct solution is to store numbers as numbers. Rest are just workarounds. You could try using a more efficient regex e.g. `CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(emp_number, '^\d{1,10}$') THEN TO_NUMBER...` or add another filter e.g. `WHERE emp_number BETWEEN '0' AND '9' AND CASE ...`. Or use the `on conversion error` solution in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have data in the employee number column that cannot be converted to a number.

Assuming that the employee number is an integer value, the following query will show you the offending rows :

```
select * from sys.employee_infor where regexp_like(emp_number, '[^0-9]');
```

You can use that where clause in your query to ignore badly formatted data :

```
select * from (
    select * from sys.employee_infor where not regexp_like(emp_number, '[^0-9]')
) where  to_number(emp_number) between 1200 and 2400
```

PS : as you are looking to compare numbers, not strings.

Another solution is to use [the `DEFAULT ... ON CONVERSION ERROR` option of function `TO_NUMBER()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html), which is available starting Oracle 12c R2. With this option conversion errors are trapped and a default value is returned instead of throwing an error :

```
select * 
from sys.employee_infor 
where to_number(emp_number default 0 on conversion error) between 1200 and 2400
```

Answer (score 0):

Under many circumstances, this will work:

```
where emp_number >= '1200' and emp_number <= '2400'
```

or:

```
where emp_number >= '1200' and emp_number <= '2400' and
      length(emp_number) = 4
```

This is not exactly the same, because it is using string comparisons and not numeric comparisons.  On the other hand, it can take advantage of indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , But when I use the single condition it returns the value but using the two condition nothing was returned . Also What if the comparison between '100' and '1000'